# Input field current color at the end

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show current color at the end of my input field.

Like this:

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

HTML

```
<label class="formlabel">Background color:</label>
<div class="forminput"><div class="forminput" id="current_color"></div><input name="bg_color" id="hexcolor" value="#bada55" type="text" /></div>
```

jQuery

```
value = $("#hexcolor").val(); 
$("#current_color").css("background-color", value);
$('#hexcolor').iris({
     change: function(event, ui){
          $("#current_color").css("background-color", this.value);
      }
});
```

Result using code above:

[image]

I get the current color as background in div but how could I place this at the end of my input field?

Comment: Please share your html. You should be able to do it using css. float:left and float:right

Comment: Keep a separate div with `position:absolute` and place it at the end of the `textbox` and change its `background color`

Comment: please add fiddle link for the html structure, and why jquery is needed for here?

Comment: So put the current_color element after the input... what does this have to do with javascript/JQuery? It's just a html question and you haven't included any html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the one exactly that you want;

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/bqrfts75/4/

[image]

#### CSS

```
.forminput {
    float:left;
    background:#e8e8e8;
    padding:5px;
}
#hexcolor {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px 3px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:12px;
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
#current_color {
    float:right;
    width:21px;
    height:21px;
    padding:3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, here is my result http://jsfiddle.net/6wkz8r4w/6/ I changed input field size to 16px so it looks equal in IE and Firefox. But in IE border color is black and not grey. I tried with `border-color: 1px solid #ACADB2;` after this my input field gets too small compared with default size in Firefox. For now it looks great in Firefox :)

Comment: Great, lower IE may not show border radius though :)

Comment: Alright, I just found out of this if I set `border: solid 1px #ACADB2; height: 1.65em;` at bg_color input it looks equal in IE and Firefox :)

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking around with CSS is the answer:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Create a css file, add something like this to the head of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aFile.css">
```

And then in your css create selector such as

```
.forminput{
 position:relative;
}
```

and similarly assign "position: absolute" to the children of the forminput.
Finally, use left and right to position those elements. 
Of course you can also use floats : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simply place color holder next to input (same height as input) and on input change just pass that value as background color. To place input next to color placeholder, float both elements. You can use `clear: both|left|right` or some [clear-fix css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for parent to take full space with floated elements inside.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.color').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('label').find('.current_color').css('background-color', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
.current_color {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#hexcolor {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  Primary color:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="hexcolor" class="color" placeholder="#fff | #ffffff | white | rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) ..." />
  <div class="current_color"></div>
</label>
<label>
  Secundary color:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="hexcolor" class="color" placeholder="#fff | #ffffff | white | rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) ..." />
  <div class="current_color"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Use** float:left

see this example

**Example:**http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/fpws88pw/

**CSS:**

```
.current_color{
    height:21px;
    width:21px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
input{
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.current_color{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is just a CSS question and just add below style to your `#current_color` element

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bqrfts75/3/)**

```
#current_color
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:153px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your color box to be after the input, then you should move the HTML element to be after the input. I also added some CSS to align things:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   value = $("#hexcolor").val(); 
    $("#current_color").css("background-color", value);

    $('#hexcolor').on('change',function(event, ui){
          $("#current_color").css("background-color", this.value);
    });

});
```

```css
#hexcolor {
  vertical-align: top;
}

#current_color {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 19px;
  width: 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="formlabel">Background color:</label>
<div class="forminput">
  <input name="bg_color" id="hexcolor" value="#bada55" type="text" /><div class="forminput" id="current_color"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using relative positioning and overwriting the popup color picker you can keep the item in position without using floats.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $("#hexcolor").val();
  $("#current_color").css("background-color", value);
  $('#hexcolor').iris({
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $("#current_color").css("background-color", this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.color-container {
  position: relative;
}
.color-viewer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.iris-picker.iris-border {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>
<label class="formlabel">Background color:</label>
<div class="forminput color-container">

  <input name="bg_color" id="hexcolor" value="#bada55" type="text" />
  <div class="color-viewer" id="current_color"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:table` is a good way to solve this: **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dyk7gmL6/)**.

HTML:

```
<div class="color">
    <span><input type="text" class="current-color" value="#333333"/></span>
    <span class="preview-color"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.color {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.color > span {
    display: table-cell;
}

.current-color {
    max-width: 100px;
}

.preview-color {
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="hexcolor" value="#444444" />
<div style="display:inline" id="current_color">frame</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   value = $("#hexcolor").val(); 
    //$("#current_color").css("background-color", value);

    $('#hexcolor').on('change',function(event, ui){
          $("#current_color").css("background-color", this.value);
    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bgbhycer/)